# Creating an ADFS authentication flow in internal corporate wiki

Tags: windows, authentication, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, adfs

Considering the context of building a corporate portal page to host a kind of knowledge management wiki, how would I approach it if I want to authenticate that page with the corporate Windows user authentication system (ADFS Single Sign On)? Can't seem to find good implementation guides.

Answer (score 1):

Your app. should use an MSAL library to talk to [ADFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/msal/adfs-msal-web-app-web-api).

There are other examples in the menu on the LHS.

MSAL libraries are available for a number of [languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview).